# Eclipse Gradle STS Plugin. Add project reference vs dependency management

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependency-management, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have Eclipse workspace with 2 projects (let's call them master and slave). I would like to use gradle dependency management for the slave project. Everything works like a charm except link to master project.

STS gradle plugin silently remove link to the master project (according to [bug STS-3082](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3082)) after refreshing dependency. I hope that I could somehow instruct gradle to add that link to my class path. I tried just one more src folder, but with no luck.

Any advices are welcome.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.5'
    compile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.4.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '../Master/src'
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

**.classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**UPDATE**

To fix this issue I have to comment line `srcDir '../Master/src'` and add to **build.gradle**

```
eclipse.classpath.file.withXml { xml ->
    def node = xml.asNode()
    node.appendNode('classpathentry', [ combineaccessrules: false, exported: true, kind: 'src', path: '/Master' ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you will need to resort to `withXml` hook in EclipseClasspath described in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html